# Passing a Path with '&' to Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, cmd

I am trying to pass a path to a batch file from another program. The other program uses BASIC as it's scripting language.

So, I am calling the batch file via the Shell() command.

In the shell command, I am trying to pass in a path that has the symbol '&'. However, by the time it gets to the batch file, the batch file treats the & as sort of an escape sequence (I think).

For example:

Path: C:\Documents\R&D\Files

```
Shell("runscript.bat "C:\Documents\R&D\Files"")
```

In the batch file:

```
variable=~1
echo %variable%
```

I am getting the following output:

> C:Documents\R

***UPDATE***

However, if I use a path like C:\Documents\RD\Files

This path will come through find and the echo will print:

C:\Documents\RD\Files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to use the variable without quotes.(Enclosing it in quotes will cause you no problems).Then you need delayed expansion (and accessing variable with `!` instead of `%`):

```
set "variable=%~1"
echo "%variable%"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !variable!
```

Here I'm assuming the first argument is something contains `&`

Another option is `for /f` :

```
for /f %%a in ("%~1") do echo %%a
```

Comment: The first argument will be the C:\Documents\R&D\Files.

Comment: @user2970916 - then test the code above and see if it fits your needs. Dont forged to pass the argument within double quotes.

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I will try to see if I can figure out why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Windows allows you to use `^` to escape the next character in a string. Try `R^&D` as shown below:

```
C:\Users\Thomas>echo R^&D
R&D
```